# knockout.js syntax issue(data-binding and modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

[image]

The right side on the attached image shows the viewModel that I am using. 
What I want to do is displaying the "candidateLocation" on a modal based on the "applicationKey" that the link has.

One suggestion that I've received from another post is as follows:

The person said he/she would use an observable on the viewModel to keep track of the current application, the one that will be displayed on the modal. It's name can be "currentApplication".

```
function application ( applicationKey, location)
{
    this.applicationKey = ko.observable(applicationKey);
    this.candidateLocation = ko.observable(location);
};


function ApplicationsVM(){

    var self = this;

    this.currentApplication = ko.observable("");

    this.setCurrentApplication = function(model){
        self.currentApplication(model);
    };


    this.applicationList = ko.observableArray([
        new application( 'key1', 'location1'),
        new application( 'key2', 'location3'),
        new application( 'key3', 'location4'),
        new application( 'key4', 'location5'),
        new application( 'key5', 'location6'),
        new application( 'key6', 'location7')
    ]);
};

var vm = new ApplicationsVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I don't quite understand how this code works since I am new to knockout.js. What does the function application() do and what does the ApplicationsVM() do? I would appreciate a step-by-step explanation of this code.

After that the person told me how to create a link to the model:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach : applicationList">
    <li> <a href="#" data-bind="click : $root.setCurrentApplication" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal"> <span data-bind="text: applicationKey" ></span> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

And the snipped for the modal itself:

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="with: currentApplication">
    <span data-bind="text: candidateLocation"></span>    
</div>
```

I understand that the modal code is trying to display the candidateLocation of the currentApplication but I am not sure how this matches with the applicationKey.

I wanted to ask the person directly, but he/she is not responding, so I decided to post it publicly.

Overall, I want to know how the provided code works and whether or not it really works as intended.

Comment: There's not much happening with the `applicationKey` other than it being used in the `text` binding of the list item. How are you rendering your `.row` elements? Using a `foreach`? I think they were trying to show you that in knockout you don't have to pass around elements, attributes and ids, because you can reference viewmodels instead. Also, your fiddle linked in the previous comments contains syntax errors and a broken knockout link, which doesn't really show that you've put much effort in to trying to understand what's going on... Try this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/1qearcok/

Comment: `application` is a constructor (and so should be `Application`). It creates an object with two members. `ApplicationsVM` is the viewmodel creation function. If you have not been through [the Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), it is worth your time.

Comment: @RoyJ How does "  this.setCurrentApplication = function(model){
    self.currentApplication(model);
  };" this function work? I dont quite understand what this does and how it works.

Comment: It is setting `vm.setCurrentApplication` to be a function that can be called from bindings in the HTML. It is used in the `click` binding in your first bit of HTML.